# Woo-commerce - Add Product - Listing Page - Design not showing properly - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Please check the attached image. I am getting broken add product page and listing design page in Wordpress - Woocommerce. I am not able to enter the title. Because after Add product page fully load. it hides the title textbox. Another issue in the Product List Page. The image column and name column are overlaying.
[image]

Please suggest me to resolve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: have you changed any core files? reset the code if you made any changes to core file or plugin, theme.

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on?". Really always seems to help. First try to do a hard refresh to the browser, clear all the history (cache, cookies and such). If that fails try, one by one, to deactivate the plugins until it works. If that fails try installing a fresh wordpress and reinstalling, one by one the plugins and then see which plugin is causing the problem.

Comment: @Ravi, No I haven't changed in the core file.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, Yes I tried to delete and reinstall Woo-commerce. it occurs when I update Wordpress and all plugins.

Comment: in this case you have to check the compatibility of plugin with WordPress version. and you have to diagnose with error debugger true and try to change theme, uninstall plugins and test everything one by one.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast ,@Ravi You both are correct. I deactivated all plugins except Woo-commerce plugin and activated plugin one by one. I found that one plugin causes the issue. Thank you

Comment: Found plugin with name SW Core. Can you please suggest to me why this plugin needed? Description in plugin = "A plugin developed for many shortcodes in the theme".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems you are using a woocommerce plugin to add the products. I can guess that you build this by making a custom post type functionality. Because normally, woocommerce has it's own icon for the post type as well as for product post type.
Please check with the plugin compatibles.

Answer (score 0):

I deactivated all plugins except Woo-commerce plugin and activated plugin one by one. I found that one plugin causes the issue. It's Works